# AxiosError 'Request failed with status code 500' after upgrading to PHP 8.x and Laravel 9.x

Tags: api, axios, xdebug, laravel-9, php-8

- I am trying to upgrade the version of my project's PHP to 8.2 and the version of my Laravel to 9.x.
- The old versions were PHP 7.3 and Laravel 8.x.
  Before upgrading everything worked as expected.
- After upgrading to the said versions I encountered a problem with some of my API Calls.

The problem is currently happening locally for me, didn't try to upload it to the server.
Sometimes (but not always), random API calls I have in my project are returning the following error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code: 
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"

config: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}

message: 
"Request failed with status code 500"

name: 
"AxiosError"

request: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

response: 
{data: '{\n    "message": "Server Error"\n}{\n    "message": "Server Error"\n}', status: 500, statusText: 'Internal Server Error', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}

stack: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500\n    at settle (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:24:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:120:66)"

[[Prototype]]: 
Error
```

This is what I receive in my console. The network tab just says: `"message": "Server Error"`

I'll mention:

- I'm using Vue 2 as my frontend and PHP/Laravel as my backend.
- My API calls are made with axios package.
- I'm on a Windows 10 OS and I'm using XAMPP.
- My IDE is Visual Studio Code if that matters.

I know the error I mentioned doesn't say too much probably and it sounds just like some general server error, but what could be the cause?

The upgrades did work fine, and I made sure I'm at PHP 8.2 with the command `php -v`.

I adjusted all the config files such as `php.ini`, `httpd.conf`, etc. (I can upload them if its needed).

One last thing I'd like to mention is that for some weird reason, when I use the Xdebug to debug my project and place breakpoints in the start of every controller function (the direction to where my API call goes in the backend) - The errors are never appearing. But this is obviously not a solution since I don't want to fill all my backend functions with breakpoints and have the Visual studio pop up every API call.

EDIT: After looking at the Laravel log I saw the following: "production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.". After a look I found the solution to use the following commands: `php artisan key:generate`, `php artisan config:cache`. They caused a different error, the very first API call of my project bugs out - .env file became none readable anymore after the commands. a code row like: "env('OKTA_CLIENT_ID')" returns null now instead of the actual value.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: If your server throws such an error, usually the frontend is not the one to blame. But please have a look at the error log of your server. If it does not yet contain any details, use a higher error reporting level

Comment: *"`xdebug.start_with_request=yes'"* -- You have configured Xdebug to try and debug **every single request/script**. This explains your *"Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client..."* messages. Note that this would work the same in your previous PHP/Laravel as long as you had Xdebug v3.x there as well.

Comment: But the above should not be the reason (as Xdebug sends it into the PHP error log only or console if it's CLI). I suggest you add trace log into your code in the endpoints that fail (you know, something like `$log->write('entering this step / finished that step');` kind of custom logging and see at what step it usually fails.

Comment: @LazyOne according to Xdebug upgrade guide from 2 to 3 they say switch "xdebug.remote_autostart = 1" to "xdebug.start_with_request=yes". And I had that option before. I dunoo, maybe those warnings regarding Xdebug appeared also before changing from version 2 to 3.

Comment: Such warning was introduced in Xdebug v3. It is made on purpose, so the user knows that the debugger connection was not successful (since that option suggests that you WANT to debug every script, so it expects that you want to have that debug session as well). Sadly there is no option to turn it off (as well us reporting when Xdebug v2 params are used). That message is sent using PHP's `error_log` functionality, so will end up in the error log and/or standard output for CLI sessions. It should not be a reason for your 500 responses TBH, but better disable and double check with tests.

Comment: About the API calls that fails its a different API call every time, sometimes the call works, some other time it doesn't. After looking at the Laravel log I saw the following: "production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified.". After a look I found the solution to use the following commands: `php artisan key:generate`, `php artisan config:cache`. They caused a different error, the very first API call of my project bugs out - .env file became not readable anymore after the commands. a code row like: "env('OKTA_CLIENT_ID')" returns null now instead of the actual value.

Comment: *" the very first API call of my project bugs out - .env file became not readable anymore after the commands. "* No clue on this. Could be something with the caching Laravel does or one of the packages. Never faced such an issue myself. Try clearing all caches and run without them (you are running it locally on your dev machine right?) Perhaps enable DEBUG in Laravel env config as well...

Comment: @LazyOne, I cleared all caches and it fixed the problem indeed, but it returned the original problem of some API calls failing. So I ran `artisan key:generate`, `php artisan config:cache` again. And then my project worked fine. Only, one last piece is missing. Now, if I clear the browsing data of my browser (for example in chrome - clearing cache and cookies), it takes me back to the issue of .env file not readable. I have to repeat everything again and it's kinda annoying.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically clear all cache + generate a key and config:cache through code whenever I first enter the project? (after a browser cache clear for example)? Or maybe is there some other more proper solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

The error: `production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified` was solved by using the command: `php artisan config:cache`.

".env file became none readable anymore after the commands" was fixed with the command `php artisan config:clear`.

Afterwards, in order to fix the repeating issue every time I cleared the browser cache what I did was adding the 2 following lines to my UserController.php file, a part of that file is being called only when the user is a new user or when the configuration has been reseted. the lines are:

`Artisan::call('config:clear');`
`Artisan::call('config:cache');`

That way, those lines will only run after a browser cache clean or when a new user logs in the website, seemed to work perfectly and fix all the problems.